# Count of ordering 6 unique objects with at most 2 objects in the original position.

Tags: combinatorics

6 unique objects are ordered in a certain way.
How many ways are there to order 6 unique objects differently so that at most 2 objects are in the original position?

For example, if the 6 objects were abcdef, it can be ordered bcdefa but not abcfed (because abc, three objects, are in their original positions). I would like to know how to count this.

Comment: Would these $6$ unique objects happen to be the letters of the word "[Orange](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/354264/139)"? (:

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones I was so confused by your question until I realized the word Orange was a link haha. So no, he and I are not trying to do the same homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I would start by counting the number of [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), which are permutations with no objects fixed, for $4,5,$ and $6$ items. Then to have no more than $2$ items fixed you can have $0$ items fixed, which is the number of drangements of $6$ items or pick $1$ item to fix (how many ways?) times the number of derangements of $5$ items, or ...

Comment: I think I can do it now. Knowing the term "derangement" alone helps a lot. Thanks for the hint!